# Subscription list function

Tags: user-roles, options

I have created a function which automatically adds users with the role of contributor to a list in which they will receive forum (modified mingleforum plugin) updates by email. My problem is that the function called by the function `is_player_subscribed()' doesn't seem to be working properly as it effectively adds the entire list each time a user registers.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'call_forum_subscribe_member_player' );

function forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    $players= get_users();

    foreach($players as $player)
    {
        $user_info = get_userdata($player->ID);
        $playeremail = $user_info->user_email;

        if(!empty($playeremail) && user_can( $player-> ID, 'contributor'))
        {                   
            $list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');                

            if( is_player_subscribed($player->ID)) //remove player if already exists (user clicked unsubscribe)
            {
                $key = array_search($playeremail, $list);
                unset($list[$key]);
            }
            else
                $list[] = $playeremail;
            update_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', $list);
        }
    }       
}

function is_player_subscribed($user_ID)
{
    if($user_ID)
      {
        $useremail = get_userdata($user_ID, 'user_email');

        $list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');
        if(!empty($list) && in_array($useremail, $list))
        {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }     
}

function call_forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    forum_subscribe_member_player();
}
```

I am trying to determine why it seems to be ignoring the second function and am guessing that it has something to do with the `$user_ID`parameter. I would greatly appreciate more experienced eyes having a look.

I should note that the function is adapted from the one in the plugin which also modifies the same option. I put the class used in a gist with the modified code in a separate file if anyone is curious or needs more information to answer the question: [gist](https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/6845919/)

Edit: var dump $list after `$list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');` gives me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " }
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) " " 
           [1]=>  string(13) "name@name.com" } 
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) " " 
           [1]=> string(13) "name@name.com" 
           [2]=> string(15) "name2@name2.com" } 
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) " " 
           [1]=> string(13) "name@name.com" 
           [2]=> string(15) "name2@name2.com" 
           [3]=> string(15) "name3@name3.com" }
```

etc. etc... When I look in `wp_options` I get `a:41:{i:0;s:2:` which coincides with the number of contributors plus one.

Comment: What is `var_dump($list);`, after this line: `$list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');`?

Comment: Hmm, I get a multidimensional array which increases the data by one each time. array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) " " [1]=> string(14) "name@name.com" } array(3) { [0]=> string(2) " " [1]=> string(14) "name@name.com" [2]=> string(19) "name2@name2.com" } array(4) { [0]=> string(2) " " [1]=> string(14) "name@name.com" [2]=> string(19) "name2@name2.com" [3]=> string(23) "name3@name3.com" } etc. etc... When I look in `wp_options` I get a:41:{i:0;s:2:" which coincides with the number of contributors plus one.

Comment: You've been around for awhile. You should know to [edit] additional information, especially code, into the question body and not add it as a comment.

Comment: You're right. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd dumped one of your `$player`s you'd have seen the issue:

```
object(WP_User)#126 (7) {
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#129 (10) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["user_login"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
    ["user_pass"]=>
    string(34) "$P$BmwzlhY1xP6JTBlbWzLPetkx8lB.Zo/"
    ["user_nicename"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
    ["user_email"]=>
    string(19) "abc@somesite.com"
    ["user_url"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_registered"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-04 09:22:08"
    ["user_activation_key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["display_name"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
  }
  ["ID"]=>
  int(9)
  // removed some unnecessary information
}
```

The ID is saved redundantly in the first level of that object, but the email address is not. It is in `$player->data->user_email`. You are accessing the variable data incorrectly.

`get_userdata` gives you exactly the same data that you already have-- try it--, so that code is wasteful. Just use the `$player` data.

Comment: You give me too much credit. I would have seen the problem perhaps but it would have taken me a week to fix it ;) I'm testing it now.